# MongoDB - How to check if an element is existed in a nested objects and return its parent or _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{      
     "_id":"5769b9600dfa9d6c158028aa",    
     "step":{  
         "1":{  
             "1":{  
                "createdBy":"John Snow",
                "qty":123
             },
             "2":{
                 "createdBy":"Alice",
                 "qty":3,
                 "note":"SerialNumber 12345678"
         },
         "2":{
            "1":{
                "createBy":"Bob",
                "qty":0,
                "note":"error"
            }
         }
     } 
}
```

I have a Mongodb Document looks like above. 
Is it possible to query all documents in collections to see if there exist a property inside the "step". 
For example Check if

> {"Note":"SerialNumber 12345678"}

exist in the any "step" of the document. And it is exist in Step 1.2 which is

> {"step":{1:{2:{"note":"SerialNumber 12345678"}}}}

We only know that it might exist in

> {"step":{x1:{y1:{//here}, y2:{}}, x2:{y1:{}}}} where {x1, x2,...}, and {y1, y2,..}.

And if it exited, I want to return its parent or "_id"

Comment: use dot notation to traverse through properties and use the find() documentation to get a query for what you're looking for and then use the projection to return specific fields such as only _id

Comment: @BrandonTomblinson "use dot notation"; do you mean by use something like db.doc.find({"step.1.2":{"note":"..."}}) ? But the x and y can be any number that greater than 1. So have to at most x * y time to check all the possibility?

Comment: for the bottom example you would use something like db.collection.find({"step.x":{$gte:1},"step.y":{$gte:1} }) and if you use indexes on the step.y and step.x properties it won't have to search every document